# ClosedXML: Is there a way I can go through every row in a Column with C#

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, closedxml

I want to go through every column in my Excel file and save each cell in a var, So I can print it out in the Console (For testing purposes).

I know how I can do it with one Cell but not with every Column and row.

Could someone help me with this. I couldn't find any good documentation to help me.

```
// Creates a workbook
XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook(@"C:\_Projekte\ProductMatchingChecker\ProjectData\test.xlsx");

// Creates a worksheet
IXLWorksheet worksheet = wb.Worksheets.First();

var test = worksheet.Cell("A1").Value;
Console.WriteLine(test);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Columns()` method..

```
// Creates a workbook
var wb = new XLWorkbook(@"C:\_Projekte\ProductMatchingChecker\ProjectData\test.xlsx");

// Creates a worksheet
var worksheet = wb.Worksheets.First();

const int targetColumn = 1; // note: first column number is 1, not 0

var cellsInTargetColumn = worksheet
    .Columns()
    .FirstOrDefault(c => c.ColumnNumber() == targetColumn)
    ?.Cells()
    .ToList() ?? Enumerable.Empty<IXLCell>(); // in case target column is out of range, so foreach won't throw null-exception
foreach (var cell in cellsInTargetColumn)
    Console.WriteLine(cell.Value.ToString());
```